# fstat getting file size zero

Tags: c, linux, file

File is there and having json data inside it. I want to know length of file.but when i try below code it but size remains 0.

```
int file_contentl_Len = 0;
int fd_0 ;

fd_0 = open(FILE_PATH_CONFIG_0, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0644);

if(fd_0 < 0)
{
    printf("\r\nError opening Config file %s: %s\n",FILE_PATH_CONFIG_0, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}

struct stat buf;
fstat(fd_0, &buf);
file_contentl_Len = buf.st_size;


printf("\r\nConfig file %s content length: %d\r\n", FILE_PATH_CONFIG_0, file_contentl_Len);
```

Comment: Why DOS-style line ending on Linux?  Most peculiar!

Comment: Even if he's on Windows, `\r\n` shouldn't be necessary; `printf` is supposed to take care of that for you properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You opened the file for writing with truncation, creating it if necessary — `O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT`.

The size of zero tells you the truncation worked, or the file was created empty.

If you wanted to read what was in the file, use `O_RDONLY` instead.  Or use `O_RDWR` and think carefully about whether to allow the file to be created.